# Delete files with a specific pattern using script in UNIX

Tags: unix, delete-file

I have some folders in unix, lets say aa, ab, ac and so on. I have subfolders inside these folders. They are numbered like 100, 200 and so on. I want to delete some sub folders in each of these main folders. The sub folders to be deleted must be greater than a specific number(say anything above 700) How can I do this using a script? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `find` command. You can do something like this:

```
find . -name '[7-9][0-9][0-9]' -execdir echo 'rm -vr' {} +
```

Of course, you may need to tweak the pattern to hit the right names, but I would need more information to help with that.

Comment: this won't work with directory names with more than 3 digits e.g. 9999

Comment: @dogbane hence my comment about needing more detail to tweak the pattern name ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
  echo Usage: $0 searchdir limit
  exit 1
fi

searchdir="$1"
limit="$2"
find $searchdir -type d |
egrep "/[0-9]+$" |
while read dirname
do
  let num=`basename "$dirname"`
 if [ $num -ge $limit ]
 then
    echo rm -rf "$dirname"
 fi
done
```

Run with:
    ./script.sh dirtosearch thresholdfordelete

When you're sure it's ok, remove the echo before rm -rf

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all using `find`.

In the following command, `find` passes the files to `sh` which checks if they are >700 and if so echoes out a delete. (You can obviously remove the `echo` if you really want to delete.)

```
find . -type d -regex "^.*/[0-9]+$" -exec sh -c 'f="{}";[ $(basename "$f") -gt 700 ] && echo "rm -rf $f"' \;
```